# Regarding one-loop 1PI graphs for the $\lambda\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

According to [Cheng and Li](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198519613) (p.32), there are only four one-loop 1PI graphs for the $\lambda\phi^4$ theory. However, I can come up with a few more diagrams that look like one-loop 1PI graphs, such as the following.

[image: one-loop 1PI?]

Therefore, I would like to know why the above graph is not included in the said exhaustive listing by Cheng and Li. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheng & Li in Figs. 2.4 & 2.5 on p. 32 are only listing the UV *divergent* 1PI Feynman diagrams in $d=4$ spacetime dimensions. In particular, OP's diagram has [superficial degree of divergence](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=renormalization&as_epq=superficial+degree+of+divergence) equal to $-4<0$, i.e. it is UV finite, and hence excluded from the list.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a 1PI graph is to give corrections to the propagator in your field theory in a non-perturbative way (well, non-perturbative in the coupling, but still a series in the number of loops). Based on this motivation, 1PI graphs are typically defined as having only one incoming and one outgoing propagator. Yours has four incoming and four outgoing propagators, and thus isn't really going to give a correction to the propagator in your theory (it will, however, produce a new $\phi^8$ interaction, among others, under renormalization).

I hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. `1PI graphs are typically defined as having only one incoming and one outgoing propagator. ` But Cheng and Li includes up to $4$-point functions in the list. `It will, however, produce a new ϕ⁸ interaction...` I am not sure I fully follow.

Comment: I only really know the treatments given by Schwartz and Peskin & Schroeder.
As for the $\phi^8$ interaction, the loop you wrote down will give a divergent contribution to any correlation function. In renormalization, the appropriate counterterms needed to absorb these infinities will include an effective $\phi^8$ term (which can be thought of as contracting the loop to a point). Fortunately, this interaction will be irrelevant (its coupling is negligible at low energies).

Comment: I expect that Chang an Li have only included the divergent 1PI graphs that are relevant for calculating renormalization quantities. Your graph is convergent, having $[p^{2}]^4$ in the denominator and a $d^4p$ in the measure.